# pre-visualize an image

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to **pre-visualize an image** in a image box before save it in a directory.
How can i do this, i use a checkbox to see if the user wants to pre-visualize or not because i dont find another way to do this without a checkbox.
I use file upload to upload the image.

```
string serverFileName = "";
serverFileName = Path.GetFileName(Upload.PostedFile.FileName);
Upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(MapPath("~/fotosPerfil/") + serverFileName);
```

i use this piece of code to save the image.

Comment: You need JavaScript. A good easy way is to examine the Wikipedia upload form

Comment: Can JavaScript reference the image file in the client file system? Or can the DOM reference such a file?

Comment: @Diogo: are the images so large that you can't upload them first to a temporary location on the server before asking the user if they want the image permanently saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded) is exactly what you need to implement. Check out Ivan's solution.

Yes, indeed you can read the path selected by the user and display the image in an `<img>` tag, all client-side prior to uploading.